# Margin left right Align different in firefox and chrome

Tags: css

I was developed my watching firefox only.after complete i open my site in chrome..then i seen alignment problem...

Code Below

`<span class="fbtopbutton">
<div id="left">
 <a href="#"><img src="/images/fb-login.png"></a> 
</div></span>`

i using this code in not proper place of the html code..(because of some php code limitation..)thats why using margin-left top and right

**Css code**
.fbtopbutton{ position: absolute;margin-top: 5px;margin-left: 27px;}

**In firefox view**
[image: firefox view]
**In Chrome View**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.fbtopbutton{ position: absolute;top: 5px;right:(however far from the right you need it to be)}
```

Ensure that the parent is also positioned absolutely or relatively.

Comment: This code not aligning proper..but this code making same effect in both browsers..thats alot :)

Comment: @user1753971 I have edited my answer. You need to set the right attribute to the distance you want between the span and the right edge of the parent.